# Set iFrame height from document.ready ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

In a jQueryUI dialog I have an iFrame which provides me a file-upload function. This upload-iframe is supposed to be 50% of the height of the dialog (using `$(window).height()`).

In the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` from the dialogfile I'm setting the height of the iFrame. Then in the iframe a same construction is used to set the height of the div inside it to correctly cover 50% height of the dialog (100% height of the iframe). In the iframe I'm using $(window).height() to set the height.

This works for all browsers including IE9, but not in IE8.

The problem seems to be that the iframe content is rendered while loading the dialog. The height the iframe gets is the height the actual iframe content needs, in my case 150px.

I've tried many things to accomplish what I want:

1. Put the code outside $(document).ready() from the dialog
2. Put the code to resize the iframe at the end of the dialog source
3. Using $(parent.document).ready() in the iframe
4. Several non-jQuery notation/syntaxis attempts to influence the height.

Unfortunately none of them did the trick.
Any suggestions on how to tell IE8 the height of 50% the parent/dialog window?

Comment: Maybe you need to use an "old-fashion" `window.onload`. It doesn't fire before all content and resources are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure thats fit your needs, but should work:

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="myiframe" onload="parent.resizeIframe(this.id)" src="..." frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

**js**

```
function resizeIframe(iframeId)
{               
    $('#'+iframeId)
        .width(parseInt($(window).width(),10))
        .height(parseInt($(window).height()/2,10));
}
```